# Logging onto website with android

Tags: java, android, cookies, https

Basically I used a firefox extension to get post and get data from a login to my school website. I want to be able to login but when I try it says "session expired please re-login!". Here is the code I have so far can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I think it has something to do with redirects because the first post should redirect to the right place but I cant get it to work and trying to get the location header throws a null pointer.

```
try {
            super.onCreate(icicle);
            CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
            CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);
            BasicClientCookie netscapeCookie = new BasicClientCookie("UserLoginInfo", "SelectedTab=StudentLogin&RedirectURL=");
            netscapeCookie.setVersion(0);
            netscapeCookie.setDomain("sisk12.hannibal.k12.mo.us");
            netscapeCookie.setPath("/");
            cookieStore.addCookie(netscapeCookie);
            localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);
            HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("https://sisk12.hannibal.k12.mo.us/hb/Default.aspx?__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&txtUserName=xxxx&txtPassword=xxxxxx&btnLogin=Login&txtSelectedTab=StudentLogin");
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpost, localContext);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            // readResponse(response.getEntity().getContent());
            //Log.w("****","Login form get: " + response.getFirstHeader("Location").getValue());
            // readResponse(response.getEntity().getContent());
            if (entity != null) {
                entity.consumeContent();
            }
            Header[] headers = response.getHeaders("Location");
            if (headers != null && headers.length != 0) {
                String newUrl = headers[headers.length - 1].getValue();
                // call again with new URL
                HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(newUrl);
                entity = response.getEntity();
                Log.w("****", "Login form get: " + response.getStatusLine());
                response = httpclient.execute(httpget, localContext);
                readResponse(response.getEntity().getContent());
            } else {
                Log.w("****", "No location header");
            }
            if (cookieStore.getCookies().isEmpty()) {
                Log.w("****", "None");
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < cookieStore.getCookies().size(); i++) {
                    Log.w("****", "- " + cookieStore.getCookies().get(i).toString());
                }
            }
            // When HttpClient instance is no longer needed,
            // shut down the connection manager to ensure
            // immediate deallocation of all system resources
            httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.e("****", Log.getStackTraceString(ex));
        }

public String readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
    String line = "";
    String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line).append(NL);
    }

    in.close();

    String page = sb.toString();
    Log.i("****", page);

    return page;
}
```

**update**

I changed my code and got this response- The following error has occurred

Error Message:Failed http request begin!
Technical Message:Thread was being aborted.
Calling Stack:_pvt_ApplicationBeginRequestParameter List:

my code is now

```
        static String regex ="name=\"__VIEWSTATE\" value=\"";
        String getURL = "https://sisk12.hannibal.k12.mo.us/hb/Default.aspx";
        String postURL = getURL;
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        HttpGet getMethod = new HttpGet(getURL);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(getMethod, localContext);
        String getString=readResponse(response.getEntity().getContent());

        int start = getString.indexOf(regex)+regex.length();
        String viewState = getString.substring(start, getString.indexOf('"', start+1));

        Log.i("****", viewState);

        HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost(postURL);
        postMethod.addHeader("__EVENTARGUMENT", "");
        postMethod.addHeader("__EVENTTARGET", "");
        postMethod.addHeader("__VIEWSTATE", viewState); //to be parsed from login page
        postMethod.addHeader("btnLogin", "Login");
        postMethod.addHeader("txtPassword", "xxxxxx");
        postMethod.addHeader("txtSelectedTab", "StudentLogin");
        postMethod.addHeader("txtUserName", "xxxx");

        HttpResponse postResponse = client.execute(postMethod, localContext);
        String postString = readResponse(postResponse.getEntity().getContent());
        Log.w("****", postString);

        HttpGet getGrades = new  HttpGet("https://sisk12.hannibal.k12.mo.us/hb/Portal/Parent/ParentLogin.aspx");
        HttpResponse response2 = client.execute(getGrades, localContext);
        String getGradesString=readResponse(response2.getEntity().getContent());
        Log.i("****", getGradesString);
```

there is a redirect in the code which should be called by the post, but I don't if apache takes care of this automatically or not and how to handle this if not?

Comment: did you set up httpclient to handle https request (not http)?

Comment: anyway, remove your id & password in that url.

Comment: I wasnt sure if I would get any help without the username and pass but I removed them now. It was making me a little nervous leaving them on the net

Comment: No I didnt do anything besides what the code here is showing. I wasnt aware I needed to do something like that. Could you give an example of how to do that?

Comment: This is my code snippet.
HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, "UTF-8");
SchemeRegistry sr = new SchemeRegistry();
sr.register(new Scheme(RequestScheme.HTTP.name(), PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(),
    RequestScheme.HTTP.port));

sr.register(new Scheme(RequestScheme.HTTPS.name(), SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(),
    RequestScheme.HTTPS.port));

ClientConnectionManager manager = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, sr);

Client client = new Client(manager, params);

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but replace your whole `readResponse()` method by [`EntityUtils.toString(response)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/util/EntityUtils.html) -- it will spare you from lots of character encoding fun.

Comment: @kingori Please post large amounts of code as an answer. This up there hurts my eyes ;)

Comment: @PhilippReichart Ok. I moved code from my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 4):

It might have something to do with the ASP.NET session cookie.

When you load the sign-in page in a browser (`https://sisk12.hannibal.k12.mo.us/hb/Default.aspx`) it sets a session cookie, `ASP.NET_SessionId`. That cookie is then submitted when the sign-in button is clicked in the browser.

But your code isn't submitting such a cookie.  Maybe it would work if you did something like this:

1. load Default.aspx
2. pull ASP.NET_SessionId cookie out of that request
3. then run your original code, but add the session cookie too

Comment: I dont understand, doesn't apache automatically log cookies? So wouldn't this value be automatically stored?

Comment: Yes, but only if you load the page that sets it first:
`https://sisk12.hannibal.k12.mo.us/hb/Default.aspx` sets the cookie initially, then `https://sisk12.hannibal.k12.mo.us/hb/Default.aspx?__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&txtUserName=xxxx&txtPassword=xxxxxx&btnLogin=Login&txtSelectedTab=StudentLogin` takes it as a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Here are my suggestions,

1. I don't see any [issue with SSL](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/sslguide.html) unless there is some JSSE configuration issue (which is least likely with latest java versions). HttpClient can handle it without any explicit configuration. And you are in-fact hitting the site. So SSL is not an issue.
2. From the error it seems it is looking for some standard session cookie in session, *even before login*.
3. In browser it works, because first, you access the login page using GET which sends the session cookie, and then use the same page to submit the POST request. The cookies are managed by browser.
4. Do the same in your code
5. **First access** the home/login page using a GET request, then use the **same instance for POST** request. The cookies are maintained in httClient instance.
6. **Don't do any explicit cookie handling** (as you are doing it using `CookieManager`). HttpClient is capable of managing cookie transparently without explicit handling. (assume that your httpclient instance is like a browser instance and you are using it for GET and POST)
7. I just check the login page, there is parameter called `__VIEWSTATE`, which is also posted along with credentials. This seems vital to make sure the login POST is not any source other than browser. If this is mandatory, then this makes your job tricky as you need to parse the login page html (which you can do using [Jericho](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html)) get that param and send the same in post request.

Following is the reference code you can use

```
String getURL = "https://sisk12.hannibal.k12.mo.us/hb/";
        String postURL = getURL;

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        GetMethod getMethod = new GetMethod(getURL);
        int statusCode = client.executeMethod(getMethod);

        //String getResponse = getMethod.getResponseBodyAsString();
        //System.out.println(getResponse);

        PostMethod postMethod = new PostMethod(postURL);
        postMethod.addParameter("__EVENTARGUMENT", "");
        postMethod.addParameter("__EVENTTARGET", "");
        postMethod.addParameter("__VIEWSTATE", "");//to be parsed from login page
        postMethod.addParameter("btnLogin", "Login");
        postMethod.addParameter("txtPassword", "xxxx");
        postMethod.addParameter("txtSelectedTab", "StudentLogin");
        postMethod.addParameter("txtUserName", "xxxx");

        client.executeMethod(postMethod);

        String postResponse = postMethod.getResponseBodyAsString();
        System.out.println(postResponse);
```

You may have write some additional code if you encounter redirection.

Comment: I changed my code (see above)  and got this response- The following error has occurred

Error Message:Failed http request begin!
Technical Message:Thread was being aborted.
Calling Stack:_pvt_ApplicationBeginRequestParameter List:

Comment: Please follow the example code which I have posted. You are using _HttpGet_ and not _GetMethod_ as suggested.

Comment: Thats because I have no GetMethod class on android, at least that I can find. Is that from an external library?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but your problem can caused by SSL connection. Try set up ssl connectivity in your HttpClient.

```
HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams(); 
HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, "UTF-8"); 

SchemeRegistry sr = new SchemeRegistry(); 
sr.register(new Scheme(RequestScheme.HTTP.name(), PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), RequestScheme.HTTP.port)); 
sr.register(new Scheme(RequestScheme.HTTPS.name(), SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), RequestScheme.HTTPS.port)); 

ClientConnectionManager manager = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, sr); 
Client client = new Client(manager, params)
```